# Railway line conundrum

Tags: electricity, electrical-engineering

I found a wire joining those 2 cement slabs. I wonder what it does. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Was there a similar wire between all the other sleepers / slabs, do you know,?

Comment: Yes, it was the same everywhere in between all slabs

Comment: Two possibilities that are complete guesses. 1. The sleepers have an inner core of reinforcing steel and the wires be may used to control any electrical buildup, generated by the train wheels/track junction, as there are metal ties connecting the track to the sleepers. 2. They may be used to limit sleeper sideways movement, although the wire looks a bit light weight for that.

Comment: Just to finish off, when I zoom in on the photo, they really do look electrically related.  If they sent a current down the sleepers using those wires, and the track warps in extreme weather, which I have personally seen in Canada, the wires may break when the sleepers move under warped tracks, letting the operator know they had a problem. When tracks warp, trains derail, no question.

Comment: Your question will be closed, because our reviewers seems to think it is offtopic. But, it will be ontopic on http://engineering.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I didn't understand the reason why? Can you be more clear

Comment: @user115962 It would be risky for me, but you can ask this on the [meta site](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com). Ask on the meta, as a new question, with a link to your current question here, why was it closed. Be polite.

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree with countTo10 on this one. Must be connected to the rebar inside giving electrical continuity to all the concrete blocks then probably connected to a ground every so many feet, thus eliminating the need to ground each and every block. But I really don't know for sure.

Comment: Everything about them is "electrically" looking, it's just that the wire, to me, looks too strong for static control and two weak for physical stability of the sleepers...I dunno,  move it to trainsSE or equivalent